# List of camera API orientations on android

Tags: android, camera

Some devices on Android do not set `Camera.CameraInfo.orientation` correctly (e.g. HTC Glacier, HTC Evo). They say that no orientation needs to be applied but in fact you do need to. Other devices are fine. Is there a list of the correct values for devices which do not implement this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging around, there doesn't seem to be a list of devices and their cameras which have the right orientations. The only real way to handle this is to provide a manual override for users who are running buggy devices.